# Return Statement in Page_Load give A Return Keyword must not be followed by an Object Expression

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have the following inide  my Page_Load on an aspx.cs file:

```
public abstract partial class ViewInvoices : DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DNN"].ConnectionString))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable salesOrders = new DataTable();
            DataTable salesOrdersDetail = new DataTable();
            DataTable recurringSalesOrders = new DataTable();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM REVINDEX_STOREFRONT_SALESORDER WHERE STATUS = 1";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(salesOrders);

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM REVINDEX_STOREFRONT_SALESORDERDETAIL inner join 
            REVINDEX_STOREFRONT_SALESORDER on REVINDEX_STOREFRONT_SALESORDERDETAIL.SALESORDERID = 
            REVINDEX_STOREFRONT_SALESORDER.SALESORDERID WHERE SALESORDER.STATUS = 1";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(salesOrdersDetail);
            adapter.Fill(recurringSalesOrders); 
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            salesOrders.WriteXml(ms, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            salesOrdersDetail.WriteXml(ms, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            recurringSalesOrders.WriteXml(ms, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
            ms.Close();
            return xml;
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to send the contents of the datatables to an xml file and save it to disk for reference by my DNN module's user interface.  When I try to run this, I receive the following error:

```
Since 'DNNSharp.Revindex.ViewInvoices.Page_Load(object, System.EventArgs)' returns void, 
a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression
```

Does this error indicate that I've placed the logic incorrectly in the Page_Load event?  If so, should I define a separate event/method to create the datatables and write results out to an XML file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

page load event handler should not return a value... change the last line from `return xml;` to simply `return;` or just remove it.